# Открытие функцией mysql_select_db базы данных из localhost

Tags: php, mysql, openserver, localhost

Использую приложение OpenServer. По адресу ..\OSPanel\domains\localhost\ разместил базу данных base.db

Фрагмент кода

```
$link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root');
if (!$link) { die('Ошибка соединения: ' . mysql_error()); }
$db_selected = mysql_select_db('base.db', $link);
if (!$db_selected) { die ('Базы данных не существует: ' . mysql_error()); }
```

Однако при исполнении этого участка кода возникает ошибка "Базы данных не существует: Unknown database 'base'". Удаление расширения базы данных с внесением соответствующих изменений в код также не даёт эффекта. Подскажите, что нужно сделать, например, куда поместить базу данных и как её назвать, для узнавания её функцией mysql_select_db.

Comment: В подключении $link к базе следует указать пароль к СУБД

Comment: Простите за мою безграмотность, я новичок в PHP, но где взять этот пароль? Как его задать? Дело в том, что у меня всего один файл ..\OSPanel\domains\localhost\base.db, и я сам его создал в SQLiteStudio.

Comment: SQLite база во-первых не откроется через расширение `mysql`, а во вторых, расширение `mysql` уже не существует. Вам рекомендуется открыть мануал и выбрать другой подход для работы с SQLite базой.

Comment: MySQL так не работает, то что вы разместили файл - не значит для него ровным счетом ничего.
Все базы должны быть подключены или созданы через сам MySQL
Покажите файл или заголовки файла БД.
Очень подозреваю что ваша база не имеет отношения к MySQL.

Comment: В смысле, сделать скриншот? И если да, то чего, программы SQLiteStudio?

Comment: Добавил везде букву i (mysqli_connect, mysqli_select_db и mysqli_error и плюс учёл разницу в синтаксисе), но всё равно база данных не открывается

Comment: Не скриншот, HEX первых 20-30 символов =) 
SQLite - соответственно для SQLite. Для MySQL - можно использовать например MySQL Gui tools, или HEDI SQL, или еще что то что умеет с MySQL.

Comment: Собсно говоря, если вы делали файл в SQLite Studio - можно не давать HEX, и так понятно что у ва SQLite база а не MySQL

Comment: то есть получается, что этот файл работать не будет? нужно делать файл в MySQL?

Comment: То есть файл вообще работать не будет в MySQL, MySQL сам разбирается как хранить ваши данные. всю работу с БД надо вести через сервер. а не файлами...
Если вам нужны портабельные базы - используйте иные сервера, например SQLite или Paradox, они работают с файлами.

Comment: Получается база данных, которую я создаю в MySQL это вообще не файл? Как же тогда эту базу данных с localhost перенести на хостинг?

Comment: Указывайте ник @ПавелСумароков вот так, чтобы пользователь видел уведомление.
Перенести базу? снять дамп и залить его на хостинг. Можно сделать самостоятельно бэкап, например в виде набора SQL запросов которые восстановят состояние базы. Можно сделать это через утилиты для снятия бэкапов.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- 1) Установите на компьютер ПО для администрирования БД MySQL(в примере будет MySQL Gui tools[image: введите сюда описание изображения])
- 2) Подключитесь к вашему MySQL серверу используя пароль\логин пользователя созданного в процессе установки (обычно root) [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
- 3) Создайте нужную вам БД, заполните ее данными.
- 4) При необходимости переноса базы на другой ПК - сделайте резервное копирование
  [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
- 5) Подключитесь к БД на которую ведется перенос данных.
- 6) Восстановите бэкап полученый на шаге 4.
  [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

### Стоит понимать

- MySQL сам разберется где и как ему хранить файлы с данными, и это не обязательно будет отдельный файл на БД или Таблицу.
- MySQL не "портативная" база данных, он не рассчитан на то что его базы будут таскать в виде файлов на "флешке" или передавать между серверами.
- Даже если вы положите файл в папку с файлами данных MySQL - это ничего не даст, файл не будет воспринят сервером.
- Все операции с данными нужно проводить через сервер, не нужно работать на прямую с файлами.

**p.s. Ответ рассчитан на новичков, если вы считаете что какое либо из утверждений неверны - так оно и есть, но не для новичка.**

Comment: спасибо. А через OpenServer можно сделать перенос, или в любом случае нужно устанавливать MySQL?

Comment: MySQL у вас входит в состав OpenServer.
MySQL это сервер БД.
Чем снять дамп? да тем же mysqldump, он находится в папке bin в MySQL

Comment: Спасибо большое) честно говоря не укладывается, зачем нужно было разработчикам MySQL настолько усложнять процесс манипуляции базами данных, но тут приходится работать с тем что есть.